# How do you shrink an image using the <a> tag element when hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple html code that shrinks an image when hovering it. Instead of shrinking the `cosmetics` image when hovered. How do you shrink that `cosmetics` image when you hover only the `hovericon` image inside the `a` tag element.

I want to shrink my `cosmetics` image when you hover only the `<a>` tag element in this line of code:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/hovericon.png"></a>
```

```css
/** Choices @Banner**/

.image-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.cosmetics {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: right
}

.haircare {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: right
}

.makeups {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.skincare {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.shrink .img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.shrink .img:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="imagecontent shrink">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="cosmetics">
      <h1 style="font-size: 33.13px;">COSMETICS</h1><br>
      <label style="font-size: 13px;">Dolore excepteur anim cupidatat tempor sit. Dolor</label><br>
      <label style="font-size: 13px;">sit ut mollit. Ut minim aliquip voluptate officia.</label><br><br>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/hovericon.png"></a>
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="images/cosmetics.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way of doing this? Please help. I'm new to css3 and its design.

Comment: Is it okay if we change the html a bit?

Comment: position of `<a href="#"><img src="images/hovericon.png"></a>` is also changing with image shrink, very hard to target.

Comment: following your HTML structure, it's only possible to achieve using javaScript. if that's okay, let me know. I will help you

Comment: Yes, It is okay for me @Lucian. Thank you in advance.

Comment: there's already answer i was thinking of, so, you use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way of doing it. With combination of some js.

```js
$('.hover-icon').on('mouseover', function() {

  $(this).parent('div').addClass('hovered');

});

$('.hover-icon').on('mouseout', function() {

  $(this).parent('div').removeClass('hovered');

});
```

```css
/** Choices @Banner**/

.image-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.cosmetics {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.hovered .thumbnail img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.haircare {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: right
}

.makeups {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.skincare {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.shrink .img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.shrink .img:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="imagecontent shrink">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="cosmetics">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/350418/pexels-photo-350418.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb">
      </div>
      <h1 style="font-size: 33.13px;">COSMETICS</h1><br>
      <label style="font-size: 13px;">Dolore excepteur anim cupidatat tempor sit. Dolor</label><br>
      <label style="font-size: 13px;">sit ut mollit. Ut minim aliquip voluptate officia.</label><br><br>
      <a href="#" class="hover-icon"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/fff000"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need Sir, but instead of zooming out the image. It will shrink the whole image along with its text.  Like the code snippet I did above.. How do you achieve that? Is it something to do with the transform scale? . Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: i personally suggest to use `$(this).parent().addClass('hovered');` so that any parent tag can take it. it's better not to define tag in such situations

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform to shrink it properly.

```
a:hover img{
 transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: it seems its not working sir/maam. Could you provide a code snippet if you may, to properly view it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/harshamotwani22/0gj3ujqd/

I'm sorry I was using transition earlier, it is transform. Please check above stated fiddle

Comment: "shrink that cosmetics image when you hover only the hovericon image inside the a tag element." Read the question again

Answer (score 0):

```
a img {
  transform: scale(1);
}
a:hover img {
  transform: scale(0.5); //shrink half
}
```

Search also for `transform-origin`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp